# Qt 5.15 macOS: distorted text in QML with font loaded using QFontDatabase

Tags: macos, qt, fonts, qml

We are developing a Qt5 application and building with Qt 5.15.2 on macOS (both on Catalina & Big Sur).

We are loading Open Sans and Ubuntu fonts in C++ using `QFontDatabase` before the `QQmlApplicationEngine` loads the `main.qml` file. These fonts have been downloaded directly from Google's Font website: https://fonts.google.com/

```cpp
// before QQmlApplicationEngine::load("qrc:/main.qml");
QList<int> fontIDs;
// OPEN SANS
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf");
fontIDs << QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/CoreUIFonts/fonts/opensans/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf");
```

In very rare case, when launching the built application (either in Debug mode, or Release mode) the text displayed in QML that makes use of the loaded font families is distorted.

[image: Ubuntu & Open Sans distorted]

[image: More examples of distortion in various parts of the UI]

The strange thing is that the distorted fonts appear only the first few times the application is launched on a new machine. After a few launches, the issue disappears (at least, we have yet to find a proper pattern). We are struggling to reproduce this issue reliably on our machines since it happens once every few days of building/testing. This is making it very hard to debug/find the root cause of the problem, and hence a fix.

We have thought that part of the issue might have to do with no qmlcache files existing. So we have tried deleting all the cache files, but this doesn't make the issue emerge again. On macOS the qml cache files that we are aware of are stored at `~/Library/<ORGANISATIONNAME>/<APPNAME>/qmlcache`. Deleting these and relaunching the application doesn't cause the font distortions to happen again.

We have the following settings applied at the start of the `main` function, before the `QApplication` and the `QQmlApplicationEngine` are instantiated and the QML is loaded. They don't seem to impact the reproduceability of this issue.

```cpp
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DisableHighDpiScaling);
QQuickWindow::setTextRenderType(QQuickWindow::NativeTextRendering);
```

The font is applied to a `Text` component as follows:

```
Text {
   font.family: "Open Sans" // or "Ubuntu"
   font.weight: Font.Normal // or Font.Bold or Font.DemiBold, etc...
}
```

The question we have is:

1. Has anyone experienced this before? A search on Stackoverflow or the QT Bugs portal has not led to finding a report of the same issue as the one we are experiencing.
2. Can you think of other tests that we could try to reproduce this issue more reliably?

Comment: What I find interesting is the bad renderings seem to be the correct character but with a transform applied to it that shears it horizontally and wraps the result back within the character's correct bounding box. Do you have any type of threaded behavior in this application – especially some that would be busy right after install and might be trying to do some text rendering in a background thread instead of on the main thread?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Thank you for the suggestion. We do have threaded behaviour and we painstakingly looked at what the code is doing differently between the first time the software launches and subsequent launches (where the problem does not occur). Turns out that at the first launch, we show a getting started video streamed from AWS using QtMultimedia MediaPlayer player in QML. If we play this video at the start, then the fonts become distorted when the QMLs are loaded using the Loader component. Our fix was to eliminate this at the moment until we have more time to look into the MediaPlayer.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, our approach to figuring this out was to compare exactly what the software was doing between a first clean install software launch and second launch of the application. We used a virtual machine with a clean macOS installation to simulate a user's computer for a fresh install of our software. And then we reviewed closely each step in the software execution to spot any differences between the first time it launched (where the problem above occurred) and the second time (no problem).

Comment: Makes sense. Just keep in mind that in every GUI toolkit I'm aware of, you cannot interact with the UI directly from any thread other than the main event loop thread. All manipulation of UI elements and their associated data should be done from the main event loop thread. If you are actually playing a video in a different thread of the application, that will definitely break this rule. You can start the player from the main thread and likely do other event driven activities while it is playing but don't try to instantiate, configure, start or stop it from another thread.